# How do I get the program to display multiple notifications on the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

i cant seem to understand how to display multiple notifications without one overlaying another. In my case it only displays one at the time.
[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUORs.jpg)

My goal is to get it to work like on the screenshot below
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh3RR.jpg)

What should I change or maybe add to my code?

chunk of code assigned for notifications

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("com.example.romanchuk.appisode.notifyId", id);
        intent.putExtra("com.example.romanchuk.appisode.show_id", show_id);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, sNotificationId /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.addLine(message);

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigText.bigText(message);
        bigText.setBigContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
        Notification notification = null;
        notification = builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_accent))
                .setContentTitle("Appisode")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri).build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(sNotificationId++, notification);
    }
```

Comment: What is your **sNotificationId** this is constant..?

Comment: this is variable
private static int sNotificationId = 1;

Comment: Check my answer, If you want multiple notifications it should be different for different notification.

Comment: Sorry for this question, but how can i do it?

Comment: If your **id** or **show_id** is int and not constant and if it will be different for each notification you can use that.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran, maybe i didnt ask it in a right way. let me rephrase is. I recieve several notifications in the blind but only one is displayed on a screen. Next notification will overlap the prev. one. I need the notifications from my application to appear, as in the "picture 2"

Comment: i need to display two or more notifications from the same app at the time

Comment: thats what I am telling if the notification id is same it will overlap, so we should give different id for different notification.

Comment: I updated my answer with adding a tag to every notification check that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show multiple notifications, You Notification id should be different, If the notification id already exists in the notifications it will override that notification.

```
notificationManager.notify(sNotificationId++, notification);
```

In this `sNotificationId` should be different for all notification

If your `id` or `show_id` is int and not constant and if it will be different for each notification you can use that also as notification id.

Or try to give different tag for each notification like this,

```
notificationManager.notify(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), sNotificationId++, notification);
```